# couple of problems with TCP in Java

Tags: java, tcp

Okay so firstly it does connect to the server so there is no problem with the connection, the following code show the connection and sending a message to the server, when I click run it doesn't open up the JFrame, the window where I can see my tool... Also I'm trying to send what I get from jMessage.getText into ows, but I get an error at this line:

```
String process = jMessage.getText();
```

Also I'd like to call osw.write(process); ONLY when I click the bSend button, so how can I use this inside the main method? Please take a look at the code, also remember the first question that my JFrame wont open in a new window showing me my tool, it just prints out the System.out.println at netbeans console:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tcpservidor;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author Damage
 */
public class TeKServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TeKServer
 */
public TeKServer() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jMessage = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    bSendMessage = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Chat Client");

    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    textArea.setEnabled(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textArea);

    bSendMessage.setText("Send");
    bSendMessage.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bSendMessageActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Message");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(294, 294, 294))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(303, 303, 303))))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                        .addComponent(jMessage))
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 291, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(bSendMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(286, 286, 286))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 319, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(3, 3, 3)
            .addComponent(jMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(bSendMessage)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void bSendMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:


}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeKServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeKServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeKServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TeKServer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    /** Define a host server */
        String host = "192.168.0.8";
        /** Define a port */
        int port = 7777;

        StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();
        String TimeStamp;
        System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");
        try {
        /** Obtain an address object of the server */
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        /** Establish a socket connetion */
        Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("Connection Established!");
        /** Instantiate a BufferedOutputStream object */
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.
        getOutputStream());

        /** Instantiate an OutputStreamWriter object with the optional character
        * encoding.
        */
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");
        TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();

        String process = jMessage.getText();
        /** Write across the socket connection and flush the buffer */
        osw.write(process);
        osw.flush();
         /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
        /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
        * incoming socket streams.
        */

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.
            getInputStream());
        /**Instantiate an InputStreamReader with the optional
        * character encoding.
        */

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");

        /**Read the socket's InputStream and append to a StringBuffer */
        int c;
        while ( (c = isr.read()) != 13)
            instr.append( (char) c);

        /** Close the socket connection. */
        connection.close();
        System.out.println(instr);
        }
        catch (IOException f) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + f);
        }
        catch (Exception g) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + g);
        }

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TeKServer().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton bSendMessage;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
public javax.swing.JTextField jMessage;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
String process = jMessage.getText();
```

causes a compilation error as it is declared in the `static main` method where `jMessage` is an instance variable. As you have a lot of code in the `main` method, I would suggest extracting it out into a `launchApp` method and call it like so:

```
new TeKServer().launchApp();
```

In the new `launchApp()` method, you would replace

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new TeKServer().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

with

```
setVisible(true);
```

> I'd like to call osw.write(process); ONLY when I click the bSend button

If you wanted to do this you could maintain `osw` as a global member variable ***but***  holding sockets open for an indefinite amount of time is a bad approach generally. Would suggest to only open a socket when needed, write & close.

Comment: I want to call the button functoin everytime I click it, but that means I have to code within where it says bSendActionPerformed, but that also means that I have to open the socket connection there too everytime I click it and then close it back. I did this and it only sends 1 message when the button is clicked, it doesnt send any more messages, eventhough it has to run through bSendActionPerformed code again and reopen the socken and listen to my message again but it doesnt do this, what would you suggest in this case?